# PL/SQL distinct date for loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to use for loop for date in my table which only cares years and months, not days.

```
CURSOR ret_cur is SELECT orderdate FROM Orders WHERE status 
= 'DELAYED';
ret_rec ret_cur%ROWTYPE;
```

I currently have

```
insert into Orders(OrderId, CustomerId, RetailerId, ProductId, Count, 
UnitPrice, OrderDate, Status) values (2,2,1,10,45,60, 
to_date('20180102','YYYYMMDD'),'DELIVERED');
```

this data type in my orders table. (its an example for format)
I want to use DISTINCT to iterate through orderdate based on YYYY-MM. (dont care Day)
I have tried select distinct to_char(orderdate, 'YYYY-MM') but I seems to not work.

for example, if i have 20180103, 20180104, 20180105 , it should be one iteration since they all have same years and months.

Comment: I don't get your question.  A cursor is used to iterate through a result set.  What do you want to iterate through?  Do you even need a cursor?  Usually, they are not needed.  What result set are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

To select days without time you could `tunc(sysdate)`. For months we have to `group by` a char-value:

```
select to_char(mydatecol,'yyyymm'), count(*) from
(
 select sysdate mydatecol from dual UNION ALL -- Fake-Table with some dates
 select sysdate - 1 mydatecol from dual UNION ALL
 select sysdate - 2 mydatecol from dual UNION ALL
 select sysdate - 3 mydatecol from dual UNION ALL
 select sysdate - 4 mydatecol from dual UNION ALL
 select sysdate - 30 mydatecol from dual UNION ALL
 select sysdate - 31 mydatecol from dual UNION ALL
 select sysdate - 32 mydatecol from dual UNION ALL
 select sysdate - 33 mydatecol from dual
)
group by to_char(mydatecol,'yyyymm')
```

Result:

```
201809  3
201810  6
```

Comment: You can also use `trunc(date_col, 'mm')` which truncates the date to the first of the month. This has the added benefit of not changing the datatype of the result (i.e. it was a date, it's still a date).

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd like to have such a collation as below :

```
with Orders
    (
     OrderId, CustomerId, RetailerId, ProductId, 
     Count, UnitPrice, OrderDate, Status
     ) as
(
  select 2,2,1,10,45,60, to_date('20180102','YYYYMMDD'),'DELIVERED' from dual
)
select o.* 
  from Orders o 
 where to_char(OrderDate,'yyyy-mm') 
     = to_char(to_date('&myDate','yyyymmdd'),'yyyy-mm');

    -- for "myDate" substitution variable use 20180103 or 20180104 or 20180105 .. etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way todo this kind of query is to truncate the date value:

```
SELECT CustomerId, trunc(OrderDate,'MM') OrderMonth
     , sum(Count) totalCount
     , sum(Count*UnitPrice) totalPrice
  FROM Orders 
 GROUP BY CustomerId, trunc(OrderDate,'MM')
```

for example...